# Commerce Discount Issue/Discepancy

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

In Craft 2 Commerce 1 one could apply a coupon code with "per email limit" during checkout, without having the email added to the order/cart model(s).
In Craft 3 Commerce 2 the same scenario yields this error;

```
Discount is limited in use to those who have supplied their email address.
```

This is probably good behavior, for the most part, but is there any way around it to have it work like in Craft 2 Commerce 1? Meaning; make coupon codes with email limits applicable to carts without an email. The reason being the convention of having your cart overview with some initial cost details, wherein you could add discounts and then proceed to checkout and shipping and all that.